# Symfony2: Integrating with a non-namespaced SDK (specifically PayPal)

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, composer-php

I've created a `PaypalBundle` and added the Paypal [merchant-php-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php) to my `composer.json` and now I've got a `vendor\paypal\merchant-php-sdk` directory. **But this SDK isn't namespaced** and doesn't seem very `OOP`. *What's the best way to access these files?*

- Should I use `require`?
- Should I do anything with `autoloading`?

I've looked into the what was done with a similar `AmazonAPI` but the Amazon code is more OOP friendly with namespaces defined, etc.

**Step 1: Composer.json 'Repository' configuration**

```
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "version": "master",
        "name": "paypal/merchant-php-sdk",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/paypal/merchant-php-sdk.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None-namespaced code can be as good OO as namespaced code.  And maybe it is better to use [an exisiting paypal bundle](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=paypal) like the [JMSPaymentPaypalBundle](http://knpbundles.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentPaypalBundle)?

Comment: Great Point about OO and I was aware JMSPaymentPaypalBundle. It looks good and JSM is a awesome SF2 contributor. However, the PaymentBundle, which the PaypalBundle belongs to, uses ORM and I've decided not to use ORM in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Composers [Classmap](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) Loading.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/", "lib/", "Something.php"]
    }
}
```

OR

If you want to require certain files explicitly on every request then you can use the [files](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) autoloading mechanism.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Vamsi, so in your example above. if the lib/ directory had 10 (non-namespaced) class files. They would all be loaded on every page request.

Comment: "All the API request and response classes are available in services\PayPalAPIInterfaceService\PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.php" I think it't better if you can test out the file method.

Comment: So .. stick to their examples and use `require`? at least for now.

Comment: download manually to some directory and load it from composer ussing file autoloading mechanism ( check updated answer )..you can also configure it to pull the code directly from github, like you have  in the question.

Comment: so once I've used the autoloading mechanism to load the non-namespaced files and begin writing code to utilize the Paypal SDK, how do I reference the classes in those files? Can I use `use`? Do I still use `require`?

Answer (score 0):

If the SDK was on Packagist, then the package author should have defined in their **composer.json** file which files to include; Composer then includes them files manually for you. For their, you can access them from the global namespace:

```
<?php
namespace Path\To\Controllers;

class PaymentsController
{
    public function processAction()
    {
        $paypal = new \PayPal();

        // code...
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a package on Packagist that gits from the Paypal SDK source. Right now, my `composer.json` is configured to do that. I'll update my question with that configuration.

Comment: My current setup leaves me with an empty PaypalBundle (which I've created). My objective is to access the Paypal SDK effectively.. All the Paypal examples using multiple `requires` don't seem current.

Comment: So you’re manually defining the source, rather than going through a package repository like Packagist? In that case, I’d surmise you’re at the mercy of the package developer. If it’s not name-spaced, it’s not name-spaced, and you’ll have to include it manually. Maybe look at dependency injection if you want it available app-wide?

Comment: correct, but there isn't anything like this on Packagist so I'm really at the mercy of myself. So if Paypal SDK code isn't namespaced, am I forced to use `require` OR can I somehow autoload them?

Comment: I found a repo which seems to have rewritten the Paypal code with namespaces, but I'd rather use code directly from the paypal team. Here's that repo : https://github.com/speckcommerce/SpeckPaypal

Comment: As I say, you’re at the mercy of the developer. If it’s not able to be auto-loaded you’ll have to manually require the files yourself. That’s why I mentioned dependency injection, as you can instantiate the library once and have it available to your app where you pass your dependency injection container.

Comment: I like the DI idea -- but I've never heard of DI'ing a library of files? Where would I learn about this? I've only DI'ed things like Database Connections, Other Services, Classes, Objects, parameters.

Comment: You would have a bootstrap or application file that requires the PayPal library files, creates the object, and then stores that object in your dependency injection container.

Answer (score 0):

- I have the same issue with https://packagist.org/packages/alchemyai/alchemyapi_php
  a none namespace package, none of the above resolved the issue. Here is my solution:
- Do not change anything from the package, composer takes care of autoload classmap for us.
- example:

> composer require alchemyai/alchemyapi_php "dev-master"

- Add its class name to the file/class you want to use like so:

> use AlchemyAPI;

- use it as normal:

> $alchemyapi = new AlchemyAPI('jrjeo94j49945hgh92h3493rhf-fake');

- last but most important is to run composer with option (source: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1150):

> composer dump-autoload --optimize

It will work, Done.